# 2d Linked List Destructor

Tags: c++

I'm working on a 2d linked list and each linked list points to the right and bottom, my program crashes each time saying that
Exception thrown: read access violation.
a was 0xCDCDCDCD.
Exception was thrown on line 4 where b = a->next.

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
nodePtr a = head; 
nodePtr b = a->next;
nodePtr c = down;
nodePtr d = c->bottom;

while (a != NULL)
{
    nodePtr temp = a->next;
    nodePtr temp1 = c->bottom;
    delete a;
    delete c;
    a = temp;
    c = temp;
}
```

}

Comment: You're checking that 'a' is not null, what about 'c'? Also, on which line is the exception thrown ?

Comment: You forgot to initialise something earlier.

Comment: The value `0xcdcdcdcd` is typically used by Visual Studio and its debugger to mark uninitialized global memory (see e.g. [this MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260966(v=vs.60).aspx)). That means if you have a variable with that value, you have not properly initialized it. Are you missing setting a pointer to `nullptr` in a constructor?

Comment: Ok, Ill take a look if i'm missing to initialize something. Thanks!

Comment: What guarantees that 'a' and 'c' have the same length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even supposing that this code works properly (that means that number of items is even):

```
while (a != NULL)
{
    nodePtr temp = a->next;
    nodePtr temp1 = c->bottom;
    delete a;
    delete c;
    a = temp;
    c = temp1; // fixed definitely incorrect assignment
}
```

You have an undefined behavior when `a` and `c` pointer are met you start delete nodes that are already deleted.

So, the proper way IMHO is to delete nodes only in one direction (I'd choose the forward direction).